# Where will you find this?

Tags: riddle

Where will you find roads without cars, forests without trees and cities without houses?

Comment: Is this a riddle you came up with?  If not, could you please cite where you got it from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In a travel guide. Travel guides may discuss significant roads, but not the cars on them; they may mention forests of tourism interest, but not the individual trees, and cities will generally be discussed in terms of tourist attractions, without mentioning private homes (except occasionally if associated with a famous denizen, or of architectural significance).

Comment: Hmm, it just feels like one of those for California would mention something like the [Chandelier Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandelier_Tree) and the fact that a car can drive through it. That said, good answer.

Comment: @Phylyp - Yes, I imagine that one coul find specific exceptions to all of them, but I mentioned only the houses because those are likely to be the most common exception. In the general case, specific items of the indicated types don't make the guide.

Answer (score 17):

I think it will be:

> On the map.

Comment: In the same sense you don't find roads, forests and cities at all though.

Comment: Most of the time the maps for directions do show roads, forests and cities.

Comment: I would be surprised if this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @maounkhan that was the goal though, right? It shows those 3 but not  pictures of cars, trees or houses

Comment: This was my first though too and to be honest I think it fits much better than the intended solution.

Answer (score 9):

You could find these things

> In the ocean

roads without cars

> The Bimini Road is an underwater rock formation in the Bahamas

forests without trees

> kelp forests

and cities without houses

> The Gloomy Octopus has been discovered building a city (nicknamed Octlantis by the scientists studying it) in Jervis Bay south of Sydney, Australia

Answer (score 5):

You can find it

> In the Dictionary ?

Comment: exactly what I thought

Comment: This will also contain cars, trees and houses.

Comment: @Rob Yes. Roads and Cars are two independent things in this. OP asks for roads without cars, which is true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> In an **Ant Colony**
>  The tunnels are roads, many ants grow fungus for food (the forests), and the living/feeding spaces could be considered cities.